# jsTree can't select leafs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

so I have here a jsTree instance, which is working fine. I'm dynamically storing datasets (with jquery `.attr()` and `.data()` ) in the list items,
the html set is precoded (no loading via ajax or whatever).

the structure looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Node1
    <ul>
        <li>Node2
            <ul>
                <li data-material-id="bpch1u1">Leaf 1</li>
                <li data-material-id="bpch1u2">Leaf 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Then i have a button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openMaterial($(this))">Open Material now</button>
```

while listening to an external script, the button is provided with a `data-material` attribute. The attribute is set correctly and i am able to read it.

what i want now is that on click of the button `openMaterial()` it should open the corresponding leaf with `data-material-id= button-material`

my function looks like this:

```
function openMaterial(el)
    {
        //get treenode with material id
        var node = $('li[data-material-id="' + el.data('material') + '"]');
    }
```

node holds an jQuery object after the call, but sadly its empty (holding the body). I believe this is because any not-opened nodes or leafs of the `jsTree` are not in the DOM. Means even if I open them and close them again, or load them they don't appear in the DOM.

I tried the jsTree functions `open_all` and `load_all` and they seem to work, but i still can't get the leaf. is there another option to get the corresponding leaf with just the `data-attribute`?

EDIT:

Another try using the built-in jsTree function `get_node`:

```
var node = $('#material_list').jstree('get_node','li[data-material-id="' + el.data('material') + '"]');
```

It's not working at all. If I call it when all nodes are closed it returns "`false`", if the nodes and leafs are opened (programmatically or manual) it returns the correct leaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got two solutions for this now:

-Bubble down the tree progressively (open one node after another)

-Open all nodes, fetch the node, fire the event, close all nodes again

I haven't tried the bubbling down yet because the second option seems more efficient to me, since i only need the data-material attribute of the leaf.

So this can be kept in just one line with one jQuery selector:

```
$('#material_list').jstree('open_all')
    .jstree('select_node','li[data-material-id="' + el.data('material') + '"]')
    .jstree('close_all');
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to traverse the internal jstree storage and get your items from there (and select them or simply reveal them):

```
var instance = $('#material_list').jstree(true),
    material = el.data('material'),
    i;
for(i in instance._model.data) {
    if(i !== '#' && instance._model.data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if(instance._model.data[i].li_attr['data-material-id'] === material) {
            instance.select_node(i); // use this to reveal the node and select it
            instance._open_to(i); // use this to reveal the node
            instance.select_node(i, false, true); // use this to select the node without revealing it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, checked it and it's working, though i think my "2nd" solution is more efficient.

Comment: As far as efficient goes - `open_all` will trigger a lot of DOM updates, and `close_all` will follow with a lot more, and the DOM query will be very very slow compared to array access, so your solution will never be as efficient as the above code (granted, it is shorter). I just updated the answer to include a version which will not reveal the node and not even touch the DOM (if that is what you need). Of course - use whatever is most convenient for you and suits your needs, I just wanted to warn future readers about the cost of `open_all` and `close_all` and the DOM lookups.

Comment: My apologies, I obviously didn't think about that... I'll keep thinking about your answer, for now (as I'm already using it) I will just use the way i figured out, though you're right that it is NOT more efficient than yours. Thanks again!